# Approve content in liferay

Tags: liferay

Ive added web content to a page with liferay but it says its not approved. How can I approve it? As far as I know I have full privilages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have just saved the article as draft (instead of publishing it - there are some buttons at the bottom of the content editor) or you have a workflow active where somebody has to approve the article - depending on the workflow it can also be multiple levels of approval.

Check ControlPanel/Workflow in the "content" section to see if workflow is active for the current community/organization (and don't mix it up with the Workflow part in the "Portal" section of control panel that just provides the global defaults.